# How to store a multi-dimensional array in cassandra

Tags: arrays, cassandra, cql, pycassa

I would like to store array-like objects in cassandra, but I need to access every element also with cql, therefore I need to build indexes. Unfortunately the size of the arrays is dynamic (but not the number of dimensions, they are predefined). What would be the most appropriate way to store an array like:

`matrix[x][y][z]`

so, if it would be an 1 dimensional (`vector[n]`) array it would be quite simple. I guess super columns would be appropriate, like

```
{key=1000 , 
    { 'matrix[]' : {
            key=0, {value:10),
            key=1, {value:33),
            ...
            key=n, {value:x)
        }
    }
}`
```

multidimensional arrays (`matrix[x][y][z]`) are a bit more complicated, I would store them like:

```
{key=1000,
    { 'matrix[ ][ ][ ]' :
        {
            key=0, {x=0, y=0, z=0, value:10),
            key=1, {x=0, y=0, z=1, value:33),
            ...
            key=whatever, {x=m, y=n, z=o, value:10),
        }
    }
}
```

But in both cases, I could not figure out how to define the column_validation_classes (I am using pycassa) ...

I also tried using composite comparators, and putting everything in standard columns like:

for one dimension:

```
{key=1000,
    {
        ('matrix[ ]', 0) : 10,
        ('matrix[ ]', 1) : 33,
        ...
        ('matrix[ ]', n) : x
    }
}
```

or multiple dimensions:

```
{key=1000,
    {
        ('matrix[ ][ ][ ]', 0,0,0) : 10,
        ('matrix[ ][ ][ ]', 0,0,1) : 33,
        ...
        ('matrix[ ][ ][ ]', m,n,o) : 10
    }
}
```

But for this case I do not know how to define the comparators appropriately if I want to add additional columns with other information:

```
{key=1000,
    {
        ('matrix[ ][ ][ ]', 0,0,0) : 10,
        ...
        ('matrix[ ][ ][ ]', m,n,o) : 10,
        'whatever' : 'who cares ...',
        ...
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I could not figure out how to build indexes for this and how to make select statements for composite comparators.

Thanks for any kind of suggestions, ideas, or solutions for my problem ;)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In Cassandra how you store your data (choice row key and column name) is dependent on how you will want to access it later.

If all the coordinates are integers then I could advise you to use a 
CompositeType(LongType, LongType, LongType) as a column name.

So that you could search by some of any of the coordinates I would denormalize my data by writing the same column to the following keys (Example of all dimension)

- DynamicCompositeType(x:LongType)
- DynamicCompositeType(y:LongType)
- DynamicCompositeType(z:LongType)
- DynamicCompositeType(x:LongType,y:LongType)
- DynamicCompositeType(x:LongType, z:LongType)
- DynamicCompositeType(y:LongType, z:LongType)

ending up with

row [x]
=> column [x,y,z] : {"stuff":"really?" ... }
row [y]
=> column [x,y,z] : {"stuff":"really?" ... }
row [z]
=> column [x,y,z] : {"stuff":"really?" ... }
row [x,y]
=> column [x,y,z] : {"stuff":"really?" ... }
row [x,z]
=> column [x,y,z] : {"stuff":"really?" ... }
row [y,z]
=> column [x,y,z] : {"stuff":"really?" ... }

(all keys are elements of the Power Set of the [x, y, z])

If you think you will always know all three coordinates of a point then you could do buckets around all dimensions to get row keys.
Let's say you want to have buckets of 64*64*64 for a 3D matrix you would save the point [x, y, z] as follow:

with X = (int) (x/64), Z = (int) (z/64), and Y = (int) (y/64)

row [ X, Y, Z]
=> column [x,y,z] : {"stuff":"really?" ... }

As an alternative to composites, concatenated string work just fine. Don't forget to write the leading zeros if you do that or else the order of the columns might give you problem if you are counting on the comparator to sort out the columns.

Note about data storage

As for storing the data I would suggest small POJO serialized put into a column, do not save one element per row if you want to be able to recover groups of elements using range queries.
My favourite serialization methods for use in Cassandra column is Jackson Json to byte or protobuf if you can be bothered defining all your objects with that.
Stay away from super columns ... STAY AWAY! Or use composite columns or dynamic composiste columns (if not all you columns contain the same format and quantity of fields)

Comment: Thank you very much...

It works, and indexing works fine too. But one problem remains, when I use cql, to state some queries, i get unformated result for the composite colums. And thus, formulating cql queries like:

select * from column where x=10 and y=12 ... or where column=(10,12) ...

Any suggestion

Comment: hi sorry to see this comment only now. My guess is that it comes from the fact that you would be using dynamic composites for keys. Not all have both dimension defined?